# Excel VBA: Maintain Employee ID column

Tags: excel, vba, unique-key

How can I add a new employee and reliably generate the next sequential EMPID?

Given:

```
EMPID  Name
12345  John Smith
12346  Jane Lepore
12347  Will Maines
```

Comment: If `A1` is `12345` then `A2` should be `=A1+1` and then drag the formula down so `A2` becomes `12346` after evaluation

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("A"))
```

And then just increment one to that, and change the column to what you need. This way if your values are sorted by anything else you don't have to worry.

Answer (score 0):

Combining @Alex-D answer and @mehow comment you could use:

`=MAX($A$2:$A4)+1`

Considering that A4 is 12347 and you are writing your next sequencial number in cell A5.